# VSCode workspaces separate extension lists

Tags: memory-management, visual-studio-code

I have been using VSCode, but I noticed that it is using a lot of memory. I had three or four document tabs open continually: a .yaml document, a .py document and a .ps1 document so I could just click on a tab and have the right shell/syntax checking. I am trying to create some workspaces so that each workspace will use different extensions e.g. one workspace for Powershell, one for yaml and one for Python, so hopefully all the extensions and shells will not load at the same time if I am using just one of the workspaces. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can install all the extensions you want globally and disable the extensions per workspace.

Got to the Extensions tab [image: Disable workspace extensions]

And click Disable (Workspace) and the extension will be disabled for the workspace. In this way you can control what extensions you want for a particular workspace.

Comment: Thank you, that worked well and it is saving memory for me! I am starting to like VSCode, really.